# Como deixar uma imagem em tons de cinza em css cross-browser?

Tags: css

Estou tentando assim:

```css
img {
  filter: gray;
  /* IE6-9 */
  filter: grayscale(1);
  /* Microsoft Edge and Firefox 35+ */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
  /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.google.com.br/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
```

Nos comentarios dos filtros são informados as compatibilidades, porém eu preciso que funcione no IE10 e 11.

Existe alguma forma cross-browser ou um webkit que inclua estas duas versões?

Comment: Só PSC, o prefixo `-webkit-` nunca vai se referir ao IE, ele é para browsers que usam o engine de renderização *WebKit* (o Chrome deixou de usar, mas mantém o prefixo).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Problema:

Atualmente não existe um modo fácil de se obter os resultados da propriedade `filter` nas versões do IE. Veja quais navegadores possuem suporte: http://caniuse.com/#search=filter

### Alternativas:

Apesar dos apesares, sempre tem um jeitinho de contornar a situação. Alguns que encontrei foram utilizando: SVG, JS e CSS*. Todas elas possuem seus prós e contras, que o desenvolvedor deve levar em consideração antes de aplicar/optar por uma ou outra.

---

#### SVG:

A solução em svg possui um bom suporte e, além de trabalhar com a imagem, pode trabalhar com formas geométricas variadas. Mas, em contra partida, não é de fácil utilização para criar um layout responsivo e dinâmico. Exemplo de código com svg:

**html**

```
<svg width="400" height="377">
    <defs>
        <filter id="filtersPicture">
            <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <image filter="url('#filtersPicture')" width="400" height="377" xlink:href="http://bit.ly/1QqyJ2D" />
</svg>
```

**css**

```
svg {
    width:500px; //Ou 100% também funciona
    height:400px;
}
svg image {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

---

#### JS:

Até o momento, por mais que use resoluções de tutoriais e respostas (SO en) que afirmam que funcionam, ainda não consegui reproduzir o efeito, pelo menos não no meu IE (Win10 IE11), mas segue o código/Link para utilização do método em JS (utilizando `jQuery` também - como seletor e botão para rodar o filter).

**JS**

```
$('#toggleDesaturate').click(function(){
    var imgObj = document.getElementById('image');
    grayscaleImageIE(imgObj);
});

function grayscaleImageIE(imgObj) {
    imgObj.style.filter = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayScale=1)';
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="imgWrap">
    <img id="image" src="http://bit.ly/1QqyJ2D" />
</div>
```

Se houver realmente suporte para este tipo de função, ela se torna a melhor opção até o momento, pois estariamos trabalhando diretamente com a imagem, podendo fazer melhor tratamento de layout.

---

#### CSS

A solução em `css` possui 2 métodos.

1. Através da propriedade `-ms-filter` *
2. Através do efeito `:hover`

1- A propriedade `-ms-filter: grayscale(1);` pode ser usada em navegadores IE até a versão 9, onde alguns usuários relataram problemas e a função acabou sendo removida a partir da versão 10, sem previsão de retorno. Veja: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530752(v=vs.85).aspx

2- Utilizando a técnica do `:hover` seria necessário ter 2 imagens. Uma versão colorida (ou original) e outra em preto e branco. Deste modo você precisa definir a imagem como propriedade background, alterando o valor da url quando houver um `:hover` no elemento. Exemplo:

**html**

```
<div class="imgWrap"></div>
```

**css**

```
.imgWrap {
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    background-image:url('caminho/imagem/logo.jpg');
}
.imgWrap:hover {
    background-image:url('caminho/imagem/logo_cinza.jpg');
}
```

Deste modo, quando houver um `:hover` sua imagem de logo muda de logo.jpg para logo_cinza.jpg. Ou vice versa.

---

Veja os exemplos:

SVG: https://jsfiddle.net/f5c2gwse/

JS: https://jsfiddle.net/q1xrLonq/

CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/egtvb1od/

---

### Considerações:

Um ponto que recomendo e, sempre analiso quando inicio um projeto, é avaliar bem quem é o meu cliente, quem é o público alvo e qual o comportamento desse público na web para analisar até onde é viável focar o desenvolvimento com suporte para IE, já que ele possui diversas limitações e até mesmo restrições.

Espero que isso ajude.

Comment: Como eu poderia fazer isto com js?

Comment: Aqui tem uma solução com SVG: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14818991

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues atualizei minha resposta com um link, dê uma olhada

Comment: Nesse link que você colocou tem a dica de como resolver com CSS :) `-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayScale=1)";`

Comment: Sim, mas ainda assim deve ser gerado através do JS. correto?

Comment: Acho que pode ir direto no CSS

Comment: Através do CSS não deu não @bfavaretto , editei minha resposta.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade parece que a forma mais assertiva será usar svg,esse IE, só da trabalho.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues sim. IE realmente da bastante dor de cabeça pra desenvolvedores web. Eu, particularmente, não faço nada voltado para IE, se funcionar, melhor, se não funcionar, não tem problema. Tudo depende do seu projeto, do seu cliente e do seu público alvo. Tenha isso em mente, já que IE é um navegador bem pouco usado. Tendo um uso de aprox. 7% (segundo último estudo que vi - tento achar a fonte depois).

Comment: @CelsomTrindade eu sei que ele é pouco utilizado. acontece que o meu sistema e de banco e eles utilizam bastante IE. o negocio e tentar mudar a cabeça do pessoal

Comment: Pois é, fica complicado! Editei minha resposta, veja se ajuda mais um pouco.

Comment: Só um complemento: dependendo do caso, não precisa de duas imagens. Pode usar as duas imagens no mesmo arquivo (2 sprites). E no caso do SVG, melhor ainda por as duas versões no mesmo arquivo, ou até mudar só as cores dos elementos com CSS.

Comment: A sim, perfeito @Bacco. Só não comentei do uso de sprite pois envolve posicionamento absoluto, tentei algo que deixe a imagem mais 'maleável'.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues se seu sistema é pra banco, aproveite pra convencer o banco a não usar essas gambiarras de sistema de segurança fajutos que se usa no Brasil, que infestam a máquina de porcaria pra dar **falsa** sensação de segurança kkk. - Esperto foi o Itaú, que começou a oferecer um browser próprio ("aplicativo itaú")como alternativa, em vez de encher o pc de lixo.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade de fato requer um cuidado maior o uso de sprites. Só comentei complementarmente mesmo, sua resposta está adequada e já levou meu +1

Comment: @CelsomTrindade Eu to querendo e arrumar um emprego no exterior pra sair dessa vida kkkk, excelente sua resposta, creio que seja essa mesmo as soluções possiveis, vou de svg!